# Browsersync + Gulp.js + XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I have the most simple job in gulp, basically copy-pasted from Browsersync website. However the page doesn't refresh upon saving and following error appears in chrome console:

[image]

(The count goes up all the time...) I couldn't find anywhere anything about this error on Browsersync I tried to use Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin for chrome or start Chrome without security settings, but the error remained. I am using Windows 10, node - 5.5.0 and npm 3.8.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I should delete this question, however If anybody will get to the same error as I did... Note: disable your adblocker. I though I disabled it for all localhosts. Seems like for Browsersync's localhost I had to disable it again...